# Laravel + fractal "deeply" nested includes

Tags: php, web-services, laravel-5

I am using fractal ([fractal.thephpleague.com](http://fractal.thephpleague.com)) to develop an API with Laravel ([laravel.com](http://laravel.com)). It is an amazing library, by the way.

In certain web service, I need to return information of several nested models, which have 3 levels deep. That is, I have a **Survey** model which has many **Survey Items**, and each one of them has, in turn, many **Survey Item Results** (each one of a user). Well, I need the data from all of them, classified, that is:

```
"surveys": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        ...,
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 14,
                ...,
                "results": [
                    {
                        "id": 45,
                        ...
                    }, 
                    {
                        ...
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                ...
            } 
        ]
    },
    {
       ...
    }
 }
```

With transformers and includes, I get the surveys and survey items info without problems, but I also need the survey item results...
That is, I need something like **2-level** "nested" includes, to get the information of the **third** level.

My best approach, so far (only returning two levels: surveys and survey items). In my controller:

```
return fractal() -> transform(
     Survey::where(...),
     new SurveyTransformer()
) -> include(['SurveyItems']) -> respond();
```

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have the include for results on your ItemTransformer?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I normally do

**Survey Transformer**

```html
<?php
namespace App\Transformers;

use League\Fractal;
use App\Survey;

class SurveyTransformer extends Fractal\TransformerAbstract
{
    /**
     * List of resources possible to include
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $availableIncludes = [
        'items'
    ];

    public function transform(Survey $survey)
    {
        return [
            'id'    => (int) $user->id,
        ];
    }


    /**
     * Include Items
     *
     * @param App\Survey $survey
     * @return League\Fractal\CollectionResource
     */
    public function includeItems(Survey $survey)
    {
        $items = $survey->items;
        if (!is_null($items)) {
            return $this->collection($items, new ItemTransformer);
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

**Item Transformer**

```php
<?php
namespace App\Transformers;

use League\Fractal;
use App\Item;

class ItemTransformer extends Fractal\TransformerAbstract
{
    /**
     * List of resources possible to include
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $availableIncludes = [
        'results'
    ];

    public function transform(Item $item)
    {
        return [
            'id'    => (int) $user->id,
        ];
    }


    /**
     * Include results
     *
     * @param App\Item $item
     * @return League\Fractal\CollectionResource
     */
    public function includeResults(Item $item)
    {
        $results = $item->results;
        if (!is_null($results)) {
            return $this->collection($results, new ResultTransformer);
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

**On my base controller**

```php
    /**
     * get fractal tranformed data
     * @param $resource
    */
    protected function fractalResponse($resource, array $includes = [])
    {
        $manager = new Manager();
        $manager->setSerializer(new DataArraySerializer()); //or what ever you like

        if (sizeof($includes) == 0) {
            $data = $manager->createData($resource)
                ->toArray();
        } else {
            $manager->parseIncludes($includes);
            $data = $manager->createData($resource)
                ->toArray();
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

then

```php
$resource = new \League\Fractal\Resource\Collection($survies, new SurveyTransformer);
$response_data = $this->fractalResponse($resource, ['items.results'])
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I have coded exactly that structure (method includeItems in SurveyTransformer and includeResults in SurveyItemTransformer), and it returns well the items and at the end of them, a key called "items.results" with a value of `null`. Any ideas of what could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: Did see results when you add dump on includeResuts method on itemtransformer?

Comment: Ok, I was using the Laravel Responder (https://github.com/flugger/laravel-responder) package in the API, and it looks like this feature is buggy within the package (https://github.com/flugger/laravel-responder/issues/33)... So I am going to change to another Laravel-fractal package or try to workaround this issue, because I have developed many things so far to change everything... Thank you very much anyway.